# Filter the array of objects with optional values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array of object, were objects can have optional `name` value, or `subject` value.

Also a have filterString.

I have to write filter function, which ckecks if one of this values include this string.

```
      const filterString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        if (filterString != "") {
          let filteredItemsList = this.state.itemsList.filter(
            el =>
              el.subject
                .toLocaleLowerCase()
                .includes(e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase()) ||
              el.name
                .toLocaleLowerCase()
                .includes(e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase())
          );
          this.setState({
            itemsList: filteredItemsList,
            filter: e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase()
          });
```

This is what i have now. I get error like `Cannot read property "toLocaleLowerCase" of undefined`, because my element have name OR subject, how i can avoid this ?

Comment: what do you want to do if the object has no `name` or `subject` ?

Comment: I know there are similar questions here with answers. Check out `?.` for Typescript 3.7 or you need to test the properties explicitly before referencing.

Comment: @FahdLihidheb  well, do nothing, do not change the state.itemList

Comment: @crashmstr actually mu problem not about typescript, more about correct algoritm

Comment: ````el =>  { const str = el.subject || el.name || ''; return str.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase()); } ````

Comment: @Alex Yes, and there are different ways depending on language specification (Typescript or JavaScript), but the exact same premise is true: check for null or undefined before accessing.

Comment: Possible duplicates within search [cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+cannot+read+property+of+undefined)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
      const filterString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        if (filterString != "") {
          let filteredItemsList = this.state.itemsList.filter(
            el => {
              const inSubject = el.subject ?
                el.subject.toLocaleLowerCase()
                .includes(e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase()) : false;

              const inName = el.name ?
                el.name.toLocaleLowerCase()
                .includes(e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase()) : false;

              return inSubject || inName;
          });
          this.setState({
            itemsList: filteredItemsList,
            filter: e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase()
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think adding validation to the items might work

```
    const filterString = e.target.value && e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    if ( filterString ) {
        const { itemsList } = this.state;
        const filteredItemsList = [...filteredItemsList.filter(
                el => {
                  const inSubject = el.subject &&
                    el.subject.toLocaleLowerCase()
                    .includes(filterString);

                  const inName = el.name &&
                    el.name.toLocaleLowerCase()
                    .includes(filterString));

                  return inSubject || inName;
              })];

       this.setState({
            itemsList: filteredItemsList,
            filter: filterString
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const filterString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
if (filterString === '') return;
let filteredItemsList = this.state.itemsList.filter(
    el => [el.subject, el.name]
        .some(
            item => item && item
                .toLocaleLowerCase()
                .includes(e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase())
        )
);
this.setState({
    itemsList: filteredItemsList,
    filter: e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase(),
});
```